# Azure API Management: How to store original response body as variable and output selected field?

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-policy

I created a simple API in Azure API Management with the purpose of creating an workItem in **Azure DevOps** Boards. I created a `<send-request>` tag within the API's policy to the Azure Board endpoint. Without specifying the response body, I receive a json formatted response including info on the newly created workItem including its ID, creator, etc. I am trying to only have the ID of the workItem to be the response body of the send-request, however, whichever I tried to filter out info on the response I always receive `{"statusCode":500, ... }` and not the intended response body the Board is sending back. Is there anyway I can achieve what I want?

I have tried `context.Response.Body.As<JToken>` and various other methods using the `context.Response.Body` code but I am not getting the intended response unless I don't specify the response-body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set-body` policy in Azure API Management to modify the response body. This policy allows you to set the message body for a request or response.

```
<set-body>@{
    var response = context.Response.Body.As<JObject>();
    foreach (var key in new [] {"creator", "etc"}) {
        response.Property(key).Remove();
    }
    return response.ToString();
}</set-body>
```

- `creator` and `etc` are placeholders for the actual keys you want to remove from the response.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. I continued to receive the original response that only consisted of  {"statusCode":500, "message":..., "statusID":...}. In the response that I wanted is supposed to include ID, rev, fields, and _links that are returned directly from Azure Board. Thanks again

Comment: Yes I am aware those are only placeholders for the actual key value pairs I want to remove. I realized I should probably clarify more. I created an API on azure with endpoint hosted by ngrok. I am trying a create an automatic error reporting system so that whenever an API fails it gets logged into Azure Board. But what I am getting confused by is that everything works perfectly fine until I start using the set-body policy...